# Not able to use the Object.values function with an object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to make an array of values of all the keys inside an object using the `Object.values(obj)`
function but it throws the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'SocialMedia | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): any[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'SocialMedia | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.ts(2769)
```

Here is the code, with the type of object:

```
{
  Object.values(data?.socialMedia).map((social) => (
    <div key={social} className="cursor-pointer">
      {renderSocial(social)}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

```
export type SocialMedia = {
  fb: string;
  insta: string;
  twitter: string;
};
```

I tried using explicitly using the `data.?socialMedia` as an object but it didn't work. I tried a workaround with a simple for loop but that does not work either.

Comment: `data?.socialMedia` can be `undefined` and `Object.values` cannot receive `undefined`

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data?.socialMedia` would give `undefined` if `data` is falsy. And `Object.values()` expect an object as a parameter; that's the error you are getting. You could fix it by doing so:

```js
{data ? (
  Object.values(data.socialMedia).map((social) => (
    <div key={social} className="cursor-pointer">
      {renderSocial(social)}
    </div>
  ))
) : (
  <></>
)}
```